# Show that $F[x,y]/(y^2-x)$ is an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I want to show that $F[x,y]/(y^2-x)$ is an integral domain, where $F$ is any field.

I know that it suffices to show that $(y^2-x)$ is a prime ideal, but that is where I'm having trouble. I let $fg\in (y^2-x)$ for some $f,g\in F[x,y]$, and I want to show that either $f$ or $g$ is in $(y^2-x)$. This doesn't seem straight forward to me. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$F[x,y]/(y^2-x) \cong F[u^2,u] = F[u]$

Or consider $ \phi: F[x,y] \to F[u]$ given by $\phi(x)=u^2, \phi(y)=u$, and prove that $\ker \phi = (y^2-x)$.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful! Is that the general method to study the structure of such polynomial rings with multiple variables? I.e. find an isomorphism to a polynomial ring with just one variable. Are there any caveats I should be aware of in general with this?

Comment: This is not a general method.

Comment: Alright, a cool trick nevertheless. :)

Comment: @M47145 Be sure you understand *precisely* what is meant by the notation $\,F[u^2,u].\,$ in this connext. Perhaps the author will elaborate.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ $ Put $\ R = F[y]\ $ in $\,R[x]/(x-r)\cong R$

Answer (score 4):

Define a map 
    \begin{align*}
 \phi :F[x,y] &\longrightarrow F[t]\\
 x &\mapsto t^2\\
 y &\mapsto t.
 \end{align*}
    Clearly $\ker(\phi)\supset$ ($y^2-x$). Now any element in $F[x,y]$ can be written as :\ $f(x,y)=a_0+a_1y+...+a_ny^n +h(x,y)$ where $h(x,y)\in (y^2-x)$. Suppose $f(x,y)\in \ker(\phi)$. Then putting the values of $x$ and $y$ in $f$ we get that $a_i=0$. Hence $\ker(\phi)=(y-x^2)$. Hence you have the answer.