# How to show that $ \phi$ is Homomorphism .?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I have some confusion on this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028960/show-that-fx-y-y2-x-is-an-integral-domain)

It is written that

> $F[x,y]/(y^2-x) \cong F[u^2,u] = F[u]$

> Or consider $ \phi: F[x,y] \to F[u]$ given by $\phi(x)=u^2, \phi(y)=u$, and prove that $\ker \phi = (y^2-x)$.

**My Question** :  How to show that $ \phi: F[x,y] \to F[u]$ given by $\phi(x)=u^2, \phi(y)=u$ is homomorphism

**My thinking** : I think $ \phi$ is not homomorphism because

$$\phi(xy)  \neq \phi(x) \phi(y)=u^2.u=u^3$$

But $\phi(xy)=u^2$  or $\phi(xy)=u $

Comment: Any homomorphism out of a polynomial ring is completely determined by where the variables are sent (and the scalars, but here we don't worry about that since $F$ is mapped to itself implicitly as mentioned by Arturo below).

Comment: It is a theorem the $R[x,y]$ has the following universal property: given a ring $S$, a ring homomorphism $f\colon R\to S$, and elements $s_1,s_2\in S$, there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\phi\colon R[x,y]\to S$ such that $\phi(r)=f(r)$ for all $r\in R$, $\phi(x)=s_1$, and $\phi(y)=x_2$. It is a defining property of the polynomial ring.

Comment: @Michael we don't worry about $F$ because it is sent to itself via the identity implicitly, not because it's a field.

Comment: What do you think that '$\phi$ [$\dots$] given by $\phi(x) = u^2, \phi(y) = u$' means? This does not explicitly specify what $\phi$ is. It does implicitly, though, since (as Michael and Arturo Magidin also say in their comment) every ($F$-)homomorphism out of the polymial ring $F[x,y]$ is uniquely determined by where $x$ and $y$ go.

Comment: okay @ArturoMagidin  i didn't know about this  theorem